# postgres update query is not working in node,js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, express, node-postgres

I have an update query which seems to be not working. The underlying database used is postgres. Could you please check why it is not working? I have included my api and schema. Thanks in advance

```
exports.patch_meetup = async (req, res) => {
    const findOneQuery = 'SELECT * FROM meetups WHERE id=$1';
    const updateOneQuery = `UPDATE meetups
      SET topic=$1, location=$2, body=$3, happeningOn=$4, Tags=$5, meetupImage=$6, createdOn=$7
      WHERE id=$8 returning *`;
    try {
        const {
            rows
        } = await db.query(findOneQuery, [req.params.id]);
        if (!rows[0]) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                'message': 'meetup not found'
            });
        }
        const values = [
            req.body.topic,
            req.body.location,
            req.body.body,
            req.body.happeningOn,
            req.body.Tags,
            req.file.path,
            moment(new Date()),
            req.params.id
        ];
        const response = await db.query(updateOneQuery, values);
        return res.status(200).json(response.rows[0]);
    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(400).send(err);
    }
};`
```

Here is my model

```
const meetupTable = CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        meetups(
            id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
            topic VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            location VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
            body TEXT NOT NULL,
            happeningOn TIMESTAMPTZ NOT NULL,
            Tags TEXT[] NOT NULL,
            meetupImage bytea,
            createdOn TIMESTAMPTZ DEFAULT Now()
        )
```

Comment: do you have an error? by the way why are you returning response methods like `return res.status(404).json({'message': 'meetup not found'});` can you try removing the return keyword

Comment: No specific error, it only return empty object { }, i removed the return key word, its still the same

Comment: Which database driver are you using? node-pg? By the way can you try after changing moment(new Date()) to new Date() because when you pass a date object to moment constructor, it wraps it and creates a moment object and it won't remain as a date object anymoree.

Comment: Yes, and also the "req.file.path" is giving the error, I wasn't logging the error to console at first, but after logging to console, I have "TypeError: Cannot read property 'meetupImage' of undefined", I saved my file(image) as binary using mutter into the database. how can it be updated in the put/patch request?

Comment: I am using node-pg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what the issue might be, but one could be you forgot to add multer middleware to the API endpoint and the other is like I mentioned in the comments, you shouldn't pass moment object, instead you should pass date object as it is.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add  multer to the API endpont. Thanks!